# Phonegap, Ember, Social Login

Tags: html, facebook, cordova, ember.js, twitter

Can anyone suggest me a good library to add SSO/Social Login functions (Facebook, Twitter, Linkedin) to a phonegap HTML5 app which is using ember.js for frontend ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most popular **Authentication Ember Addon**: http://ember-simple-auth.com/

**SSO Ember Addon**: http://vestorly.github.io/torii/

They work together nicely and you get the best developer UX out of the box.